# Как рисовать изображения на python

Tags: python, python-3.x, графика

передо мной стоит задача написать бота для бронирования столиков. Есть несколько столиков, в бд написано какие из них заняты, а какие нет. Задача состоит в том что бы можно было нарисовать картинку наподобие этой:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно брать значения из бд, потом генерировать картинку в реальном времени и красным помечать занятые, а зелёным свободные.
Как такое можно реализовать?

Comment: Pillow поможет в этом

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В этом поможет библиотека **[Pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)**. Можно пойти разными путями (зависит от фантазии),но самый простой - вставка изображений.

Нужны входные изображения(например,зеленые и красные круги) и координаты для вставки.
Простейший пример:

```py
from PIL import Image
 
img = Image.new('RGB', (256, 256*3), 'white') # (256, 256*3) - размер полотна, соответственно ширина,высота. 'white' - цвет background'a.
img1 = Image.open('1.jpeg')
img2 = Image.open('2.jpeg')
img3 = Image.open('3.jpeg')
img.paste(img1, (0,0)) # Где (0,0) - это координаты, соответственно x, y
img.paste(img2, (0,256))
img.paste(img3, (0,256*2))
 
img.show()
img.save("out.jpg")
```

Источники : [pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) , [пример](https://www.cyberforum.ru/python-graphics/thread2235050.html)